# Android L (5.0) the listview long click not working sometimes

Tags: android, listview, focus, onitemlongclicklistener

```
mTreasureBoxView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                mTreasureBoxView.startEditMode(position);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I have set child view focusable = false. but not fix that problem.  this phones has this problem.  三星A7000（5.0.2） 、华为GEM-703L（5.1.1）、 LG-h818B（5.1）、HTC E9+(5.0.0)

this is parent view  SlidingUPPanel .  it's dispatchTouchEvent();

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

        if (!isEnabled() || !isTouchEnabled() || (mIsUnableToDrag && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || isDragSetting()) {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        final float y = ev.getY();
        final float x = ev.getX();

        Log.i(TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent: action " + action);

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch = false;
            mPrevMotionY = y;
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            float dy = y - mPrevMotionY;
            mPrevMotionY = y;

            if (!isViewHit(mScrollableView, (int) mInitialMotionX, (int) mInitialMotionY)) {
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            //增加滑动距离判断,必须滑动到顶部才能让ScrollableView控制touch事件
            if (getScrollPosition(mScrollableView, mIsSlidingUp) > 0) {
                mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch = true;
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }

            if (!isExpanding(dy)) { // Collapsing
                if (mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch) {
                    MotionEvent up = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
                    up.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                    super.dispatchTouchEvent(up);
                    up.recycle();

                    ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                }
                mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch = false;
                return this.onTouchEvent(ev);
            } else if (isExpanding(dy)) { // Expanding
                if (mSlideOffset < mAnchorPoint) {
                    mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch = false;
                    return this.onTouchEvent(ev);
                }

                if (!mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch && mDragHelper.isDragging()) {
                    mDragHelper.cancel();
                    ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                }

                //增加滑动距离判断,必须滑动到顶部才能让ScrollableView控制touch事件
                if (mSlideOffset >= mAnchorPoint) {
                    mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch = true;
                }
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (mIsScrollableViewHandlingTouch) {
                mDragHelper.setDragState(ViewDragHelper.STATE_IDLE);
            }
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

and this is getScrollPosition() method .  for determine if should dispatchTouchEvent to next view ..

```
 /**
     * 判断是否可以进行拖动操作
     *
     * @param scrollableView 目前只支持百宝箱TreasureBoxView 的适配
     * @param isSlidingUp
     * @return position > 0 可以进行滑动
     */
    private int getScrollPosition(View scrollableView, boolean isSlidingUp) {
        if (scrollableView instanceof TreasureBoxView && ((TreasureBoxView) scrollableView).getChildCount() > 0) {
            TreasureBoxView lv = ((TreasureBoxView) scrollableView);
            if (lv.getAdapter() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            //编辑默认过程中
            if (lv.isEditMode()) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (isSlidingUp) {
                View firstChild = lv.getChildAt(0);
                return lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() * firstChild.getHeight() - firstChild.getTop();
            } else {
                View lastChild = lv.getChildAt(lv.getChildCount() - 1);
                return (lv.getAdapter().getCount() - lv.getLastVisiblePosition() - 1) * lastChild.getHeight() + lastChild.getBottom() - lv.getBottom();
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I found a special thing.  if getScrollPosition() >= 0 , it works `  but that may not let my slidingUpPanelView scroll down.  can't do that.

Comment: show us the relevant part of your code that is now working as expected.

Comment: Ok, showing you now~  tks